# C# How to show a text bubble on a user control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm developing an user control in .NET 3.5. As reaction to some event, I would like to show a simple bubble containing a short text on this control, similar to the well-known system tray notification bubbles. I'm sure this is a very easy task, could you give me a quick hint?

Comment: WinForms                       .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx)

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip myToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
myToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
myToolTip.Show("Some text", this.WhereToShow);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ToolTip` class -- set `IsBalloon` = `true` to get the bubble effect.

Answer (score 4):

Drop a **NotifyIcon** control onto your form, then call the **ShowBalloonTip** method of your control.

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon myIcon; // generated by the designer
// more designer code, then your code:
myIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "My Title", "My Text", someIconReference);
```

Comment: I hate it when people vote down an answer with no explanation :P

Comment: Perfect as I was looking for a solution and am already using a NotifyIcon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a popup control for this (in WPF)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(VS.95).aspx)